# did not get output with layout page in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, layout, laravel-blade, master-pages

I am new to laravel framework, want to use laravel layout master pages, and used to include child pages in master page. here is my header and footer page and app.blade.php is my master page, where i am using @yield to show data. but it did not work for me. my output is showing blank.

app.blade.php (Layout master page)

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    
             
    
        <title>Master Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
            <div>
                    <div>
                            @yield('header')
                    </div>
    
            <div class="content">
                    @section('content')
                        <h1> Body </h1>
                    @endsection
            </div>
                          <div>
                                  @yield('footer')
                          </div>
    
            </div>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Header.blade.php

```
    @extends('app')
    
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title></title>
    
        <style>
            .header
            {
              height:100px;
              width:100%;
              background-color: aquamarine;
            }  
            </style>
    
    </head>
    <body>
        
    <div class="header">
        @section('header')
           <center>  Layout Header Master page </center>
        @show
    </div>
    
        
    </body>
    </html>
```

footer.blade.php

```
    @extends('app')
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>Document</title>
        <style>
            .footer
            {
              height:100px;
              width:100%;
              background-color: aquamarine;
              padding-top: 50px ;
            }  
            </style>
    
    </head>
    <body>
        
        <div class="footer">
            @section('footer')
              <center>   Layout Footer Master page </center>
              @show
        </div>
        
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

web.php (Route)

```
Route::get('/masterpage','studentcontroller@viewmasterpage')->name('masterpage');
```

studentcontroller.php

```
  

    public function viewmasterpage()
       {
           return view('layouts/app');
       }
```

Comment: Where is the studentcontroller file??

Comment: i edit my question again, with add student controller file.

Answer (score 1):

**Problems:**
There are some problems in your blades.

1. Every opening `@section` Tag needs a closing `@endsection` Tag.
2. The section Tags should everything that you want to display in between.
3. You don't need to add the whole `<html> etc.` you can simply add the necessary code
4. I think the content should be a yield because you might want to insert the content of other pages there..

I also think you are confusing `@include`and `@yield`
If you want to outsource your header and footer you can simply @include('yourFolder/footer') and it inserts the code

---

**Solution:**

1. Change the `@yield` to `@include`
2. Change the `@section` to `@yield('content')`

---

**Examples:**

File named: header.blade.php

```
  <div class="header">
     <center>  Layout Header Master page </center>
  </div>
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <title>Master Page</title>
</head>
<body>
        <div>
             @include('header')
        <div class="content">
             @yield('content')
        </div>
             @include('footer')
        </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

afterwards you can create a new view: example.blade.php

```
@extends('layout.app')
@section('content')
//put your content here
@endsection
```

Answer (score 0):

header.blade.php (Just use the code remove others)

```
@section('header')
   <center>  Layout Header Master page </center>
@endsection
```

footer.blade.php (Just use the code remove others)

```
@section('footer')
   <center>   Layout Footer Master page </center>
@endsection
```

app.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <title>Master Page</title>
</head>
<body>
        <div>
             <div class="header">
                 @include('header')
             </div>

        <div class="content">
             @yield('content')
        </div>
             <div class="footer">
                 @include('footer')
             </div>
        </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

studentcontroller.php

```
   public function viewmasterpage()
   {
       return view('layouts.app');
   }
```

Comment: By using include, the @section can be removed

Answer (score 0):

You are misunderstanding the @extends, @yield and @section directives.

@extends uses another blade file, and fills in the @yield directives with the @sections it defines.

Say you have `app.blade.php`

```
<html>
    <body>
         @yield('header')

         @yield('content')

         @yield('footer')
    </body>
</html>
```

You could then have say `landing.blade.php`

```
@extends('app')

@section('header')
    <header>I am the header for the landing page!</header>
@endsection

@section('content')
    <div>I am the content for the landing page!</div>
@endsection

@section('footer')
    <header>I am the footer for the landing page!</footer>
@endsection
```